# Can't find docker logs in Google Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy a docker container using google cloud run.
The image is built successfully using cloud build, however there seems to be an error when deploying the container even though nothing shows up in the logs.

[This is the error message I get on the service URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lYFZ.png)

The error probably occurs at the docker container level but I can't find a way to access the docker logs. No errors appear on the cloud run logs.
Everything works perfectly fine locally.

[Here is an extract of the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwEBv.png)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Check the Cloud Build logs

Comment: Yes I already checked : no errors there

Comment: There are three steps: build, deploy and run. One of those failed. Review the logs for each step until you find the error.

Comment: Where can I find the deploy and run logs ?